# Do I need to enable javascript for PhantomJS when using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: nunit, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I have a testsuite in NUnit running on both IE and Chrome webdrivers. But when I wanted to try headerless PhantomJS (Ghostdriver) I can't get it to excute the actions I want to perform.

Having issues with easy stuff like

```
[TestFixture]
class PhantomJSTest{

    protected IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup() {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(@"..\..\..\..");
    }

    [Test]
    public void PhantomTest() {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(adress);
        driver.FindElement(selector).Click();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown() {
        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

When the click is performed something should be set in my db, so when going back to that page manually I should be able to see it. The NUnit test itself is set to succeeded, but the action never happens. This is especially apparent when trying to do something based on the earlier action. Any help would be appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you following activities:

1) try to relaunch your   selenium  hub with node(-s) based on phantomJs.

2) try to use instead of

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(adress);
```

this one:

```
driver.get(URL);
driver.findElement(selector).click();
```

3) also see phantomJs documentation to get all phantomJs capabilities:

GhostDriver extra Capabilities

- phantomjs.page.settings.SETTING = VALUE - Configure page.settings on
  PhantomJS internal page objects (windows in WebDriver context) . [Reference](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html)
- phantomjs.page.customHeaders.HEADER = VALUE - Add extra HTTP Headers
  when loading a URL   . [Reference](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html)

PhantomJSDriver (Java-binding) Capabilities

- phantomjs.binary.path - Specify path to PhantomJS executable to use
- phantomjs.ghostdriver.path - Specify path to GhostDriver main/src.js
  script to use; allows to use a different version of GhostDriver then
  the one embed in PhantomJS
- phantomjs.cli.args - Specify command line arguments to pass to the
  PhantomJS executable
- phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args - Specify command line argument to
  pass to GhostDriver (works only in tandem with
  phantomjs.ghostdriver.path)

More details one can get at [GhostDriver page](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)

Also  look through [phantomJs command line options](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) . This info might be helpful for you as well.

Hope this helps you.